# How to Enforce Width on Element with Border?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) for my page layout and I want to insert a [CSS3 Box Shadow](http://www.webdesignshock.com/css3-box-shadow/) in a column.

The only problem I'm having is that the box shadow has a 1px border, and this is enough to cause my second column to wrap to the next line. If I remove the border it aligns up fine.

If I subtract 2px from the column width, it looks exactly how I want. However, I'd like to take advantage of Bootstrap's fluid layout (which is based on percent rather than pixels), so there's no easy way to simply make the `<div>` 2 pixels narrower than whatever it would otherwise be.

I really dislike the way that borders do not stay within an item's width. Does anyone see a way to have my `<div>` respect the current width even with borders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

and the border's width will be added inside the box.

Here is an example with two divs that have 100x100 sizes and 20px border. The first one has 'box-sizing', the second one has not : http://jsfiddle.net/y3zxC/ .

Comment: Is that trailing hyphen a typo?

Comment: Seems to work. Excellent tip! Looks like I'm not the only person who has ever wanted the width to be the real width.